# How to get original value of scale without trim two decimal point in canvas.toJSON() in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, scale, trim

I am working in one image editor in which there are some facility :
like set image  as canvas background and add image object into canvas.

I am using fabric js version 1.7.22. and can't update right now.

Let me explain whole scenario :

First I set image as background by using following code :

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage("url", function() {
  canvas.renderAll();
}, {
    scaleX: canvas.getWidth() / image.originalWidth,
    scaleY: canvas.getHeight() / image.originalHeight,
});
```

So the value of scale in above code is somthing like this :

```
scaleX:  0.1252875648597568542
scaleY:  0.149856546546546456545546
```

This is set perfect. but when I convert this canvas into json , then scale value is **trimed** in **json**. and when I load again that json into canvas, my image size is not perfect set into canvas background. because some value is **trimed**

Is there any patch that make json that contain same value as canvas elements contain.

Here is fiddle for demo of trim scale value in json.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/q9r20zgy/

Also, Please read comment in fiddle.

If any patch available for prevent trimming this value then Please mention here.

Comment: I have a same issue , fabric js automatically trim that value. can you override that toJSON() fucntion ?

Comment: I have not much more experience of fabric js to update it. so i can't override that function. if any one can override then it will helpful for us.

Comment: @mayurkukadiya Use fabricjs tag, not fabric.